# Combine 'like' and 'equals' (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
+------+----------+-------------+----------+
| id   | name     | name_orig   | year     |
+------+----------+-------------+----------+
|  1   | movie    | film        | 1987     |
|  2   | game     | toy         | NULL     |
|  3   | picture  | art         | 2018     |
|  4   | audio    | voice       | 1        |
+------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

When I use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `name` LIKE 'a%' OR `name_orig` LIKE 'a%' AND `year`='1'
```

It code get line 3 and 4, instead of only 4

And I try fix it by use this changed code

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`name` LIKE 'a%' OR `name_orig` LIKE 'a%') AND `year`='1'
```

But now MySQL returned an empty result.

How I can search in 'name' and 'name_orig' and not forgetting about 'year' to get the desired result (line 4)?

Comment: try removing quotes for 1

Comment: What type is your `year` column? Should you perhaps be using ``AND `year` = 1`` (no quotes)? (Although I'd expect MySQL to coerce it.) (Your second query is correct in terms of logic.)

Comment: Trying this locally, it works for me with your query as shown, whether `year` is an `int` or `varchar(...)` column.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tested it on a fiddle and same ...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the single quotes around the number `... AND year=1`

Comment: MySQL will coerce, it would appear the data isn't as described in the question.

Comment: Yes we can't answer with the data given.

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't problem.

Answer (score -1):

Even with a int in year I got line 4, I tested it on https://www.db-fiddle.com/

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  name varchar(255),
  name_orig varchar(255),
  year int
);
```

then insert :

```
INSERT INTO test (id,name, name_orig, year)
VALUES ( 1, 'movie','film', 1987 ),(2, 'game', 'toy', NULL),(3,'picture','art', 2018),(4, 'audio', 'voice', 1)  ;
```

the query

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE (`name` LIKE 'a%' OR `name_orig` LIKE 'a%') AND `year`='1'
```

the result :

```
id |    name  | name_orig | year
------------------------------------
4  |    audio | voice     |      1
```

Comment: Unclear, at db-fiddle.com it work, but at my server - no

Comment: It means you havn't give the same data so we can't answer